# Xcode image assets for both iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

Have a full working project on iPhone, and now I'm porting it to iPad. Chose the Universal option, and now most images look blurry on the iPad... I think it's because on the .xcassets catalog it's choosing the @1x images instead of the bigger ones. I know that this is possible to fix if I go through EVERY image, and make it also for iPad, and copy the @2x and the @3x to that. But that's a lot of boring work...
Any better fix on this?

Answer (score 0):

You are right in believing that @1, @2, @3 designate a resolution.

But what you are looking for is to use a different image entirely when it is on the iPad. Which makes sense because the aspect ratios are typically very different.

The missing piece of the puzzle is that you need to add a suffix to your iPad image name when adding it to your asset catalog:

```
firstImage@2x.png
firstImage@3x.png
firstImage@2x~ipad.png
```

Answer (score -1):

App icons are divided by platform, but other images are not. Those are selected based on screen resolution (1x, 2x, 3x).

Do you have Auto-Layout issues that are causing your images to be resized for iPad?

Comment: "But that's a lot of boring work" <---- I think that is the problem :)

Comment: Hi guys, I ended up doing the thing where I chose iPad in the image assets, and dragged them all to the 1x and 2x. It looks good now on the iPad Mini, but on the iPad Air, for example, things are different even though I'm doing scale = frame.size.height / 768 (it's landscape)

Comment: What's the typical process on this?